# Are there any RL algorithms / techniques well-suited to the single timestep setting?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I am working in a setting where an agent gets to make one decision and one decision only for each state in a batch of states; in other words, it's presented with multiple states, and no matter what decision is made for each, the next state is always terminal for each. After making the decision, the agent doesn't get to find out the rewards for its actions for ~20-30 minutes, making the learning process a bit slow as well. The state space is countably infinite (although there are 16 discrete actions), so I have already ruled tabular methods out.

Here are some theoretical questions I'm grappling with:

- Because there is never a non-terminal next state, this makes any method relying on TD (eg. DQN) useless, correct?
- Am I correct in classifying this as a model-based setting, where the full transition matrix is described by all states -> terminal state with probability 1?
- Are there any algorithms that fit the single-time-step, non-tabular, off-line, model-based setting?

Comment: Single-step MDPs are called bandits. If you google it you will find many algorithms :)

Comment: THANK YOU! I knew there was probably some name for them I didn't know which has prevented me from finding the best algorithms.